# cvs checkout time series

Tags: cvs

We have a cvs archive, and I can get any version of any file I want.   However, is there any way to just get the code as of a certain date and time?  I don't see any options to request that.  I'd like the ability to walk through a cvs archive day by day and do metrics automatically, perhaps a visualization of what happened to the code over time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check out a specific date:

> cvs co -D "2010-10-10 22:15:59 GMT"
>   mypath/myfile

See e.g. http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cvs/ for the detailed docs (option `-D`).

Comment: do you have a way to do this for a folder, e.g. all files recursively? If so, I have a question open at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122716/cvs-recursive-get-of-files-to-particular-date