# CVS Recursive Get of Files to Particular Date

Tags: cvs

I'm looking to do a recursive get of cvs files in a particular cvs repository directory at a particular date.

I see something similar for a particular file at: [cvs checkout time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587679/cvs-checkout-time-series)

I would like a solution which can get all of the files in a recursive manner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same command will do a recursive get if you specify a folder name instead of a specific file name.